# Mapping language to countries in Java?

Tags: java, icons, flags

I have famfamfam country icons, now I would like to show flag for language in my application. Is there any way to map language to country? I know that there can be many countries using same langauge or countries might use many languages. But most likely all languages are used in some countries, so is there any way to map languages to countries, so I could display flag icons for langauges ?

Comment: I think you'll have to do these associations manually in your code somewhere. In pseudo-code: for x language display image named xxx.png with path xxx_path. I doubt there's a real need for something more complex than this, unless you planned to translate your website in tens of languages.

Comment: The first tricky one is English. Do you show the flag of England, United Kingdom or USA?

Comment: Well there are 247 famfamfam flag icons, so I need all those flags to be mapped to languages if it is possible, automatically..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JRE gives you a default [Locale](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault%28%29) information for the current installation in platform independent manner. There you have information about country and language. Users may adjust this settings to their needs.

All other is to map the country_language code to an imgae file (DE_de.jpg) for example.

Answer (score 2):

First, don't do this. [Country flags are no good **language indicators**](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/flags.html), they are country indicators, and you will often offend your users if using the flag of another country than their own to indicate their language - or there are multiple same flags for the different languages spoken in this country (in Asia and Africa this would be often).

There are only a very small number of languages which actually have own flags, like Esperanto.

---

If you really want to do this, there are some ways:

- create a database of language/country yourself, for example like Johan showed. Or better yet, a database language => flag, since this is what you really want (and this supports the Esperanto flag, too).
- You can ask your Java JRE about the supported locales (Locale.getAvailableLocales), sort them by language, and grab a random country from the list of supported country variants for this language. Often there would be only one, thus no problem. For bigger languages like English, Arabic, Spanish, French you could select one country flag randomly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `enums` could be useful, e.g.,

```
enum Language {
   Swedish(Country.Sweden), 
   English(Country.England, Country.USA), 
   German(Country.Germany);

   private Country[] countries;
   Language(Country... countries) {
       this.countries = countries;
   }

   public Country[] getCountries() {
       return this.countries;
   }
}

enum Country {
   Sweden, 
   Germany, 
   England,
   USA;
}
```

Which can be used like:

```
Language lang = Language.English;
lang.getCountries(); // England, USA
```

The next suggestion would be to let `Country` take a `Flag` as constructor argument (just  as `Language` takes a `Country`). Then you could use something like:

```
for(Country c : Language.English.getCountries()) {
    System.out.println(c.getFlag());
}
```